# What is the plural form of "doubt"?

Tags: grammatical-number

"If you have any doubt", let me know." 
"If you have any doubts, let me know."

Both sound correct. Are there any subtle differences in meaning?

Comment: Careful or you’ll come off sounding like an East Indian or a Mexican, both of whom [often use *doubt* where a native speaker would use *problem*](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/4183/2085). :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can "doubt" sometimes mean "question"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/can-doubt-sometimes-mean-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Doubt* can be both a mass noun and a countable noun.**

So one can be *filled with doubt* (mass noun), one can have a *a number of doubts about something* (count noun), and one can also have just a *single doubt about the whole complex process* (count noun).