# What is the history of the IndianEnglish usage of "doubt" to mean "question"?

Tags: meaning, etymology, subcontinental-english

I've observed a significant number of questions on SO & SE, presumably written by folks use [Indian English](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/294125/indian-english-what-usage-is-allowed-for-doubt-meaning-question), in which the word "doubt" is used where "question" should have been used.  The sentences usually look like "I have a doubt about [interesting topic].."

My question, then, is: how or why did Indian English shift the meaning of "doubt" from its usage in British English?  I'm looking for any historical development of this usage.

Edit required by SE - the latest comments on literal vs. idiomatic translations are more what I'm after. How did the word "doubt' take on this non-BritEng usage in India?

Comment: You might have your answer under the question you've already linked to. http://english.stackexchange.com/a/294126/50044

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can "doubt" sometimes mean "question"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/can-doubt-sometimes-mean-question)

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac  I'm looking more for the etymology of the Indian-English usage, not the fact that that's the source of this confusion.

Comment: You might also refer http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4727/i-have-a-doubt-about-whether-this-phrase-is-acceptable-english

Comment: Surely it isn't a change in meaning, it is just phraseology.  They ask a question to allay their doubt.

Comment: I am failing to see anything Indian English specific about "question" "doubt" or even "uncertainty" being broad synonyms.

Comment: My guess would be that it was taken over from some other Indian language.

Comment: @GEdgar - could be Spanish.  *Tengo una duda* is literally "I have a doubt" but what it actually means is *I have a question*.

Comment: @user662852 "Teacher, I have a doubt about what you said". In InE that means "Teacher, I have a question". In AmE or BrE that would mean "Teacher, I think that what you are saying may not be correct".

Comment: I have always considered this to come from, "I have some doubt as to whether my understanding of this topic is completely correct. Could you help me understand it more clearly."

Comment: It took me a long time to get used to seeing this usage of the word. I still find it jarring.

Comment: When I see strange uses of a word that are common in another country, my general assumption is that their native language uses the same word for both meanings, and the wrong translation has been adopted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The root of this usage can perhaps be traced to one Indian word: *Shankaa*. The word *Shankaa* does represent *doubt* with the sense as in British English. However, it does get used to convey one more sense: a state of 'confusion', i.e., partial understanding enough to make one capable of seeking a clarification. Often this state doesn't get referred to as a state of having a *question* in mind, since the question itself may not be very clear and precise, and it may also be an invalid one. Secondly, *questioning* also sounds like being a bit aggressive, conveying a feeling of posing as a *challenger*. Posing *doubts* sounds more polite and correct. So, the teachers ask questions and the students have doubts for clarification! Thus, *Doubt* when used to represent a question becomes more friendlier than *Question*.

Comment: This seems great! Do you have any references or evidence to improve it?